# Multi threaded issue with myMethod()

Tags: java, multithreading

I came across this question and I am trying to figure out the answer.

This is the question:

> Assuming a threaded environment, and without knowing anything else,  what is the potential problem with myMethod()?  How can we fix it in the simplest way?

What is the issue with `myMethod`?

```
public class DummyTest {
    private static final String FUBAR = "fubar";

    public boolean myMethod(final MyObject bar) {
        if (bar.getFoo() != null) {
            return bar.getFoo().equals(FUBAR);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public interface MyObject {
        String getFoo();

        void setFoo(String o);
    }
}
```

Comment: who says bar itself isn't null?

Comment: @Stultuske That's a standard Java question; if the API for `myMethod` doesn't say that it accepts null as an argument, an NPE is entirely reasonable without further ado.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking `bar.getFoo()` twice which in multi threaded environment can have different results. `MyObject` is an interface which its methods can be not synchronized .

You also need to add null check for `bar` and you don't need null check for `bar.getFoo()` if you change you code (see below)

You can replace with one liner method:

```
return bar != null && FUBAR.equals(bar.getFoo());
```

Or with ternary conditional operator

```
return bar == null ? false : FUBAR.equals(bar.getFoo());
```

Comment: Your fix is not self-explanatory. I suggest you explain the problems you've solved.

Comment: @Shloim true, added explanation

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- added multi threaded comment about solution

Answer (score 1):

(In addition to `bar` potentially being null).

Potentially, `bar.getFoo()` could return different values on multiple invocations.

Only read it once; and check it for equality with `FUBAR` in a null-safe way:

```
return Objects.equals(bar.getFoo(), FUBAR);
// or
return FUBAR.equals(bar.getFoo());
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the obvious where `bar` may be null, the double call to `bar.getFoo()` is problematic. If we assume that other threads are running, then bar may be changed between the two calls to `bar.getFoo()` and return two different strings.

A solution would be to call `bar.getFoo()` only once and save the returned `String` as a local variable.

```
public boolean myMethod(final MyObject bar) {
    if (bar == null)
        return false;
    String foo = bar.getFoo();
    if (foo != null) {
        return foo.equals(FUBAR);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

- Note: Even in non-multithreaded environment, `bar.getFoo()` may return different values for every call.

Comment: That doesn't even require multi-threading. There's nothing to force an implementation of the interface to return the same thing on multiple invocations, so you could still have this in single-threaded code.

Comment: @AndyTurner You're technically correct, but in a non-multithreaded context allowing a method that matches a JavaBean accessor to behave that way is arguably a fundamentally broken API anyway.